# trying to have selectable dice and sides

Tags: python

i am trying to generate being able to have a number of dice and then selecting the number of sides on the dice this is my code how would i make this work

```
print("\n") #Creates new program
print("Welcome...")
print("You are are playing a game of dice, this is a two player game, who  ever rolls the highest number wins")
name1 = input("What is Player 1's Name?") #Inputs "player 1's" name 
print("Hello", name1)
name2 = input("What is Player 2's Name?")
print("Greetings",name2)
from random import randint
Dice = input("Please select number of dice you would like to use (atleast 1)")
Sides = input("Please select number of sides on dice you would like to use")
print("You have selected", Dice," dice and", Sides,"Sides")
Roll11 = int(randint(Dice,Sides))
Roll12 = int(randint(Dice,Sides))
print ("Player 1's Roll")
print(Roll11)
print ("Player 2's Roll")
print (Roll12)
```

Comment: What's wrong with it? What output do you get? What is the specific issue? Please edit accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   print("Welcome...")
    print("You are are playing a game of dice, this is a two player game, who  ever rolls the highest number wins")
    name1 = input("What is Player 1's Name?") #Inputs "player 1's" name 
    print("Hello", name1)
    name2 = input("What is Player 2's Name?")
    print("Greetings",name2)
    from random import randint
    Dice = int(input("Please select number of dice you would like to use (atleast 1)"))
    Sides = int(input("Please select number of sides on dice you would like to use"))
    print("You have selected", Dice," dice and", Sides,"Sides")
    Roll1=0
    Roll2=0
    for i in range(Dice):
        Roll1 += randint(1,Sides)
        Roll2 += randint(1,Sides)
    print ("Player 1's Roll")
    print(Roll1)
    print ("Player 2's Roll")
    print (Roll2)
```

Changes: First, the first line is unnecessary in your code. Second, you were applying `int` to the wrong line. `randint` returns an `int` but `input` returns a `string`. Third, you were generating a random number between `Dice` and `Sides`. I modified to generate `Dice` random numbers between 1 and `Sides`

Comment: also how do i make it loop and the function to work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Problem, I can see, is this line:

```
Roll11 = int(randint(Dice,Sides))
```

You are trying to pass string values as integer parameters.

try to use it like this:

```
Roll11 = randint(int(Dice), int(Sides))
```